# In what way was the way of learning in Israel different from the Babylonian to cause R' Zeirah to fast?

Tags: talmud-bavli, bava-metzia

The Gemmorah [BM 85a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Metzia.85a.21?lang=bi&with=Steinsaltz&lang2=en):

> "ר' זירא כי סליק לארעא דישראל יתיב מאה תעניתא
> **דלשתכח גמרא בבלאה מיניה** כי היכי דלא נטרדיה"

> "When Rabbi Zeira ascended from Babylonia to Eretz Yisrael, he fasted one hundred fasts so that he would forget the Babylonian Gemara so that it would not hinder him"

Of course, the two Talmudim look different, the Babylonian describing much more arguments, stories, Agadetah, etc, but in what ways the Israeli Talmud was different from Babylonian to cause R' Zeirah to fast 100 fasts to forget the Babylonian Talmud?

EDIT: It appears that the term גמרא does not represent the Talmud as a book but as a specific scholarly approach.

Comment: I think they just mean the halachos presented in the Yerushalmi, no?

Comment: Actually, some say it was 300 fasts, and some say 900

Comment: I believe this is mentioned somewhere in Yevamot as well? Somewhere in the second half? Or possibly Chagiga? IIRC the explanation was in one of the commentaries there...

Comment: Chassidus explains the difference in terms of אור ישר and אור חוזר, direct revelation of G-dliness vs. reflective revelation.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @shayachagigah's idea, the Ben Yehoyada https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.85a.21?lang=bi&with=Ben%20Yehoyada&lang2=en (Ben Ish Chai) says an intresting idea:

רַבִּי זֵירָא, כִּי סָלִיק לְאַרְעָא דְּיִשְׂרָאֵל, יָתִיב מֵאָה תַּעֲנִיתָא דְּלִשְׁכַּח תַּלְמוּדָא בַּבְלָאָה מִינֵיהּ כִּי הֵיכִי דְּלָא נִטְרְדֵיהּ. נראה לי בס"ד לא בחר בתלמודא דבבלאי מפני המחלוקת שיש בו לכן ישב מאה תעניות כמנין מדון [272].
ונראה בודאי שלא התפלל שישכח גוף התלמוד כי תורת אמת הוא רק רצה שישכח סדר הלימוד שלהם כי סדר לימודם זה בזה מוליד ומסבב שיריבו זה בזה בלימודם שכל אחד נכנס בדברי חבירו ומקשה לו רבות קודם שיתיישב בדבריו וגורם על ידי זה בלבול הדעת זה צועק מכאן וזה צועק מכאן וכיון דהורגל בלימוד זה בבבל מקטנותו וכל הרגל שהורגל בו האדם מקטנותו קשה עליו לפרוש ממנו לכך הוצרך להתענות ולהתפלל על עצמו שישכח אותו הסדר של הלימוד אשר הורגל בו ויערב לו סדר הלימוד של בני ארץ ישראל שהם נוחין זה לזה בהלכה ואין אדם נכנס לתוך דברי חבירו ואם חבירו אמר דבר של סברה לא יקפחנו בקושיות לסתור דבריו אף על פי שרואה קושיות בדבריו אלא יהיה מתוני להתיישב היטב בדברי חבירו ואדרבה הוא ישתדל לעשות להם קיום.
וישוב וחזר וישב מאה תעניות כדי שבזכות מאה תעניות שהם מספר ימים [100] יאריך ימים רבי אלעזר ולא יצטרך הוא לסבול עול ציבור ועוד ישב מאה תעניות כמנין בגהנם [100] בלא יו"ד כדי להנצל מאש גהנם ואחר שהתענה מאה יום בעבור זה עשה מבחן לעצמו באש התנור כל שלושים והיינו מבחן [100] עולה מספר מאה שרצה לעשות מבחן על המאה תעניות אם הועילו לו או לאו.
ואף על גב דאמרו רבותינו ז"ל (חגיגה כז.) תלמידי חכמים אין אור של גהינם שולט בהם קל וחומר מסלמנדרא הוא לרוב ענוה שבו לא בטח על קל וחומר זה ועשה תיקון לעצמו בתעניות אלו אי נמי לאו בעבור עצמו עשה כי יודע בעצמו שאין בו עון שירד לגהינם ח"ו ורק לפעמים הצדיק יורד לגהינם בשביל להעלות נשמות לכך התפלל אפילו שיורד לתוכה לפי שעה לא ישלוט בו האש אפילו כל שהוא.

The idea I think he is saying is: Rebbi Zeira left the seder limud of Bavel because of the machloket, therefore when he went to Israel he fasted 100 times as the gematria of מדון (strife/arugment) is 100. But it's not that chas veshalom that Rebbi Zeira wanted to forget the Torah that he learnt, but rather he wanted to forget the seder halimud, which was usually through machloket, one Rav goes within another Ravs words, and before there is an answer it's one big confusion on what the bottom line is. Therefore he fasted 100 times to forget that seder limud and went into the seder limud of Bnei Eretz Yisrael which are more in comfort, they don't enter into each others words, and even if there are rejections they try to uphold answers. He goes into more length on this idea, but this is the general premise.

Comment: I don't get it - why does it take 100 fasts to stop arguing?

Comment: @AlBerko, because מדון which means strife equals 100 in gemetria, so he fasted 100 times corresponding to this strife, to get out of the certain method of learning he was used to (like bitul). Maybe because fasting raises one spiritually, and the Yerushalmi is more holy because of no machloket. This is a common theme in the Ben Yehoyada where we find that certain Tanaaim and Amoraim did stuff for a certain number of times and the Ben Yehoyada explains that they did it for certain reason. Another example of this is in Gittin 56a where he explains why Rebbi Tzadok fasted specifically 40 years.

Comment: The Gematry of מחלוקת is 584 so why not fast that many? Do you realize how lame this apologetics is?

Answer (score 0):

See Gemara Sanhedrin 24a (from sefaria)..

מאי בבל א"ר יוחנן בלולה במקרא בלולה במשנה בלולה בתלמוד (איכה ג, ו) במחשכים הושיבני כמתי עולם אמר ר' ירמיה זה תלמודה של בבל:

The Gemara asks: What is the homiletic interpretation of the word Babylonia? Rabbi Yoḥanan says, as a tribute to the Jewish community of Babylonia and its Torah scholars: It means mixed with Bible, mixed with Mishna, and mixed with Talmud. Other Sages had a different opinion of the Torah in Babylonia: With regard to the verse: “He has made me dwell in dark places, as those that have been long dead” (Lamentations 3:6), Rabbi Yirmeya says: This is the Talmud of Babylonia, which is not as clear as the Talmud of Eretz Yisrael.

Rashi comments..במחשכים הושיבני - שאין נוחין זה עם זה ותלמודם ספק בידם

Comment: Whose addition is it "which is not as clear as the Talmud of Eretz Yisrael"?

Comment: The last sentence sounds like Rashi is saying two things: (1) the sages fight and (therefore?) (2) they do not have as clear an understanding of the material